# how to open bootstrap datepicker in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-bootstrap

could you please tell me how to open bootstrap datepicker in angular js .I have two field **name and data**.I want to open datepicker on click of date field .here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/elrOTfEOMmUkPYGmKTdW?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularMoment']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, moment) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  console.log(moment)
  var d = new Date(613938600000);
  $scope.c = {
    name: {
      name: 'abc'
    },
    date: {
      name: moment(d).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
    }
  };

  $scope.onclick = function() {
    if (!moment($scope.c.date.name).isValid()) {
      alert('Everything is wrong dude');
    } else {
      alert('Everything goood');
    }
  }

});
```

any update

Answer (score 1):

Please replace the input field with this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="x.name" is-open="open" data-ng-click="open = true" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
```

I have added these directives at  the input

<...  is-open="open" data-ng-click="open = true" ...>

Add these to directives to your datepicker inputs.
This is should work. Try in your plunker

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to go this route, but my suggestion would be to leverage [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker). Opening a datepicker is made fairly easy with this library, along with other bootstrap functionality without having to port bootstrap entirely.